Migrate an Ubuntu installation to a new Dual Boot?
I want to upgrade the hard drive of my laptop a Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3, it has a 500Gb with a Ubuntu installation that I use to work but I needed more memory, so I bought a 1Tb 2.5 SSD since the laptop has an empty slot to add a new SSD 2.5 drive. In the end, I will have the 500Gb NVMe and the 1Tb SSD 2.5
I want to install in the 500Gb drive Windows and migrate the Ubuntu installation to the 1Tb so I keep the programs, and configurations adding the dual boot to use Windows and Ubuntu when needed
How could I do this without losing my current environment of Ubuntu?

I always suggest a clean new install & restore from your normal backup. Housecleans cruft & proves that your backup is complete while you have old install to get anything you missed. If UEFI system, be sure to use gpt partitioning. Microsoft requires gpt for UEFI installs. Others may suggest various ways to create an image & restore it, but any clone means you cannot reboot with both drives connected as duplicate UUIDs & GUIDS are not allowed or you have to go thru process of changing them.
